# AngularJS Initializing a Navbar Service

Tags: json, angularjs

I've written a directive and associated controller for a navbar, which shares data with several services, like user information.  I want to create a service to pull down JSON that will populate the currently hardcoded links of the navbar, and which will be shared outside the component through $route resolve etc so the currently active link and its JSON is available to different views etc.

When and where is the best place to initialize a component service like a navbar using $http that will only need to make a request once, and not have the navbar missing at any point onload?  Using provider and dropping it in .config seems heavy handed according to the docs, but it's the only provider available in .config, the shorthand .service and .factory are not.

Using service with .run():

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    /* Navbar Component */

    angular.module('component.navbar', [
        'component.navbar.controller',
        'component.navbar.directive',
        'component.navbar.service',
    ])

    .run(function( NavbarService ) {

        NavbarService.getJSON();  // handle promise here and set NavbarService.navbarJSON using a setter?
    });

})();


(function() {
    'use strict';

    /* Service */

    angular.module('cfbc.component.navbar.service', [])

    .factory('NavbarService', ['$http', function( $http ) {

        var that = this;

        this.navbarJSON = '';

        this.getJSON = function() {

            $http.get('app/data/cfbc-loan-types.json')
                .success( function( data ) {
                    that.navbarJSON = data;  // can't use $scope it seems throughs an error
                });
        }

    }]);

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the initialization logic in the .run() block instead of the .config() block so that your service can make use of $http to initialize itself at application initialization, especially if this is an application-wide service that will be consumed by multiple controllers/routes.

Comment: Thanks @rchawdry, so if a service is application wide drop them in .run() and if local to their component keep them in their associated controller and let them load on $compile and pass back a promise?  So it'll look something like this: myApp.run(myService) { myService.getNavJSON() }

Comment: Yes to the first part and last part of your comment. I was little confused by the middle part regarding load on $compile and passing back a promise.  Are you talking about returning a promise from your service that is then used in the compile function of your directive or were you trying to pass back a promise from a directive?

Comment: Sorry, I'm relatively newb to AngularJS.  For example, I've seen some people drop the $http.get into the controller and wrap it in a function that is later invoked, and I've also seen it not wrapped in a function, which I thought meant it would run when the application was initialized and that particular controller was eventually digested.  I'm having a hard time getting my head around Angular and what might be some best practices, in this case the best way to be loading config json data application wide and within a specific component to avoid any blips or access issues on load.

Comment: $http.get is sometimes wrapped to abstract the calling syntax to make a service easier to use.  For instance, in a controller, you could use myService.getPerson("P1") to get a person or you could use $http.get(...params...).  As a best practice, raw $http.get()s should generally be done in services as opposed to controllers to minimize dependencies (i.e. actual location of an $http resource).  Keep at it, though, Angular is great once you get over the first couple of times.  My first StackOverflow question was much more basic than yours when I first started :)

Comment: I do have one last question if you have time.  I've got multiple modules, such as: app-service, app.controller, etc for high-level app artifacts, and similarly I've got component modules, for example component.navbar has dependencies like component.navbar.controller, component.navbar.service, etc.  Would you add the .run at the app-level, or on the component-level module?  Would it matter?  Seems to me like it wouldn't matter, but I can't verify either way.

Comment: In the end no matter what I'll always need to return a $http promise from the service and then set the active navigation item afterwards, right?  You're right Angular is great, but I don't think I've ever been so lost (or bewildered), will definitely keep it up.  Thanks :)

Comment: I added some example code above for where/how to handle returned data